# How to sort only some rows of table-listobject in an Excel worksheet with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have an Excel worksheet with a formated table in it (ListObject, name = "`tbl1`"). Column 1 are productnumbers and column 2 is the corresponding productname which I get from another worksheet with the **VLOOKUP**-function. The other columns contains also informations to the product, but entered manually.

If the row is not filled with a product, in the column 1 is the value "*`(put productnumber here)`*" so the user know, what to fill in. Also in my VLOOKUP-formula is in an IF-formula like: **`=IF(A3="(put productnumber here)","",VLOOKUP([..]))`**.

Now I want to sort the table ascending by column 2 (productname), but not including rows with empty productnames.

How to do this with VBA?

I tried this code, but it sorts the whole "`tbl1`" including the rows with empty productnames, so these appear at first an then the rows with the products:

```
Sub SortTable1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Bezeichnung As String
    
    ' Arbeitsblatt und Tabelle definieren
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Bezeichnung = ws.name
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("tbl1")
    
    ' Bereich der zu sortierenden Zeilen definieren
    Set rng = tbl.Range.Rows("2:8") ' Hier werden die Zeilen 1 bis 7 angesprochen
    
    ' Sortierung konfigurieren
    With rng
        .Sort key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't directly sort *part* of a table. What you might do is sort the table in descending order to get the 'blank' items to the bottom, then filter the table to hide the blank rows, then sort the table A-Z before removing the filter. That should leave the 'blank' items at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method suggested by [@Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582863/how-to-sort-only-some-rows-of-table-listobject-in-an-excel-worksheet-with-vba#comment135025787_76582863) and this is the result, that works for me:

```
Sub SortTable()

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("tbl1[productname]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
            xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("tbl1[productname]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
            xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        .SortFields.Clear
    End With

    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Maybe some lines could be deleted (As a VBA-Beginner I used the macro-recorder form Excel).